# grep sentence between (and including) two patterns

Tags: linux, grep

I want to extract sentences which start with

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/
```

and end with

```
/
```

For example, I want to extract the following without the x's

```
××××××https://www.instagram.com/p/BRhNDg5jne7/××××××××
```

I have already tried

```
grep "https://www.instagram.com/p/*/"
```

However, it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression, `https://www.instagram.com/p/[^/]\+/`

```
#!/bin/bash
data="××××××https://www.instagram.com/p/BRhNDg5jne7/××××××××"
echo "$data" | grep -o 'https://www.instagram.com/p/[^/]\+/'
```

The magic part is `[^/]\+/`, it grabs everything up to and including the next forward slash.

Sample output from the above script.

```
zb@server ~ $ ./tmp.sh 
https://www.instagram.com/p/BRhNDg5jne7/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep :

```
echo "××××××https://www.instagram.com/p/BRhNDg5jne7/××××××××"  | grep -Po "(?s)(http(.*?)(\/p\/.*\/|\/\Z))"
```

output:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BRhNDg5jne7/
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: since the question had some changes since I posted my answer, so did my understanding of it.

If all your rows have the pattern `xxxx`, then all you gotta do is a regex replace with `sed`. I.e.:

```
sed 's/xxxx*//g'
```

If you first need to `grep` the rows, then pipe `sed` after `grep`. I.e.:

```
grep "https://www.instagram.com/p/" | sed 's/xxxx*//g'
```

Depending of the real pattern you have, this approach may or may not be of use.

Comment: hope you are removing, instead of printing.

Comment: @SivaPrasath please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

no need of perl regex You can try :

```
grep -o "https://www.instagram.com/.*/"
```

Comment: You probably want a non-greedy match, or something like `https://www.instagram.com/foo/ bar baz other stuff/` will match the entire thing. You can do it by passing `-P` and changing `.*` to `.*?`